# How to set the Sitecore default application options for all backend users?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Looking at improving backend performance on our Sitecore installation I can see that adjusting some of the application settings leads to considerable gains - e-g- unchecking "prefetch collapsed sections" does wonders, as does hiding the validation bar and standard fields.

But is there any way of setting these options for users without asking them to do it themselves, and is there any way of limiting which options they can actually set?

Comment: Make sure you send a message to Sitecore support as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John West recently published a blog about about doing this via a `LoggedIn` pipeline processor for a particular setting. You can use that as a model to handle this for any settings:

[Automatically Show the Quick Info Section in the Content Editor of the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/12/Automatically-Show-the-Quick-Info-Section-in-the-Content-Editor-of-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)

Comment: Excellent work from John West again. Pity this isn't a simple configuration option though.

Comment: I agree. Looks like a great shared source module idea though!

Comment: Oooh, yes please. Somebody, anybody? :-)

Comment: anybody who visits this in 2021+, the post can now be found here: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/automatically-show-the-quick-info-section-in-the-content-editor-of-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms